# Можно ли написать "возражающее письмо"?

Tags: стилистика

Здравствуйте. Можно ли написать "возражающее письмо" или "возражающий комментарий"? Или лучше предпочесть вариант "письмо с возражением"?

Answer (score 2):

Можно использовать термин: **выражающее несогласие** (протестующее, оппонирующее) письмо.

Возражающее письмо ― это скорее **из условной авторской лексики**, например:

Словечко это ― странное словечко, ничего не опровергающее, **ни на что не возражающее**, ничуть даже не бранчливое, но стоит его произнести, и для «хороших» прогрессивных людей ― окончательно дискредитируется та вещь, по адресу которой оно произнесено. [К. И. Чуковский. Два слова о космополитизме и национализме.  (1903)]

Answer (score 1):

Выражение "возражающее письмо", скорей всего, нужно воспринимать как метафору. А вот форма "письмо-возражение" мне кажется вполне приемлемой.